# Function that determines angular velocity?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I see that someone posted the same problem a year ago, but the answer didn't quite give enough info. Here's the question:

A movie crew is working on a scene that involves filming a car moving at a high speed. For one perspective, a camera is positioned and fixed at a spot 50 feet from the car’s path (see point C below). Construct a function s(x) that determines the speed (in radians per second) at which the camera should turn to keep the car in frame when the car is at point B, which is x feet from the point on the path that is closest to the camera (point A). Assume the car is moving at 90 miles per hour in the positive x direction.

Diagram based on the description:

C

|

| 50 ft

|

A---------B

I'm confused as to what to do once I find an equation θ=some function of x.
dθ/dt = (dθ/dx)(dx/dt) where dx/dt = 132fps?? I'm at a standstill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. By constructing a right triangle between C, A, and the car's position, you can see that $\theta = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{50}\right)$. Then, by the Chain Rule,

$s(x) = \frac{d\theta}{dt} = \left(\frac{d\theta}{dx}\right)\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right) = \left(\frac{50}{x^2 + 2500} \text{ radians per foot}\right)(132\text{ feet per second}) = \frac{6600}{x^2 + 2500}\text{ radians per second}$